# Window function syntax error at over clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm solving a hackerrank SQL problem which you can see [here][1] and I have already solved it using some other method but I want to try the window function for the same, so I have run a basic query to understand the window function.

```
SELECT salary, SUM(salary) OVER (ORDER BY salary) AS running_total
FROM Employee;
```

but I got the below error.

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 4: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
> check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
> right syntax to use near '(ORDER BY salary) AS running_total FROM
> employee' at line 2

I'm pretty confused why it's throwing an error.
P.S: the query I posted above is not solving the problem, it's just a try to understand the window function, if you can solve the whole problem using the window function and write it in the answer that also will help me learn more. if you need any more details please mention them in the comments.

```
Table name- Employee
columns:
employee_id-> integer
name-> string
months-> integer
salary-> integer
```

**Mysql version - 8.0.20**
[1]: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/earnings-of-employees/problem?isFullScreen=true

Comment: What's your mysql version?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Looks like your MySQL is 5.x which does not implement window functions. Upgrade to 8+ version.

Comment: @D-Shih it's mentioned in the question also, once again here you go, https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/earnings-of-employees/problem?isFullScreen=true

Comment: @Akina  idk the version, since it's HackerEarth's default SQL IDE.

Comment: This is not a version. Execute `SELECT VERSION();` and provide complete output.

Comment: Please use mysql 5.8 version.

Comment: @RahulBiswas , you mean MySQL v8? Assuming that MySQL v5.8 _does_ exist, it's never released.

Comment: Sorry @FanoFN it will 8.0

Comment: @Akina Mysql version is 8.0.20.

Comment: This version cannot produce shown error message on shown SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, your MySQL version is less than 8+, and therefore does not support window functions.  Here is an alternative to your current query which should run on your MySQL version:

```sql
SELECT
    salary,
    (SELECT SUM(e2.salary) FROM Employee e2
     WHERE e2.salary <= e1.salary) AS running_total
FROM Employee e1
ORDER BY salary;
```

Comment: thank you @Tim Biegeleisen , but i want to know whether I can solve the problem using window function or not? and if It's possible i want the window function version answer.

Comment: ...you already solved the problem using window functions, it is just that your MySQL version does not support the syntax.